# executeprocess error in nifi

Tags: hive, apache-nifi, beeline

i have hive in hdinsight cluster and nifi in my local machine. 
i am trying to execute a hive script from executeprocess processor which has properties set as below:

```
command: hive
command argument: -f /home/name/firstq.hql
Redirect Error Stream: true
```

i have controller services to hiveconnection pool. when i start the processor, the error is thrown as shown below:

```
o.a.n.processors.standard.ExecuteProcess ExecuteProcess[id=d5db18b2-0159-1000-6569-c054490cbfa5] Failed to create process due to java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "hive": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "hive": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

org.apache.nifi.util.ReflectionUtils Failed while invoking annotated method 'public void org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteProcess.shutdownExecutor()' with arguments '[]'.
```

i have tried the command argument by giving the local machine path too. though same error is thrown.

in the script, i am trying to insert one row into the existing table.

please help me what am i doing wrong.

thanks

Comment: Is your NiFi instance running as another user?  Additionally, if you do a `stat <full path to hive>` what do you see?

Comment: yes i am running as nifi user. where do i check stat <full path to hive>? user@hostname:$ stat /usr/hdp/2.4.4.1-5/hive/bin/hive
  File: â/usr/hdp/2.4.4.1-5/hive/bin/hiveâ
  Size: 1127            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 801h/2049d      Inode: 1967825     Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2017-01-27 06:33:24.402044000 +0000
Modify: 2016-11-03 06:54:59.000000000 +0000
Change: 2017-01-11 20:30:28.975780708 +0000
 Birth: -

Comment: Is the firstq.hql file visible to the 'nifi' user?  If it is in another home directory, I could see this potentially being a permissions issue.